# Footer on MergeAdapter by CommonsWare

Tags: commonsware-cwac

I'm using MergeAdapter by CommonsWare to merge two ListViews.
How can i add a fixed footer to this list?

I'm doing this way:

```
MergeAdapter adapter = new MergeAdapter();;

View msg=inflater.inflate(R.layout.inicio_msg,null);
((TextView)msg.findViewById(R.id.msg_text)).setText(tw.getText());
adapter.addView(msg, false);

View news=inflater.inflate(R.layout.inicio_news,null);
adapter.addView(news, true);

setListAdapter(adapter);
```

Where and how i put the fixed footer?

Comment: What is a "fixed footer"?

Comment: It is a fixed footer , that is, will always be on the screen , regardless of how many records have in listview

Answer (score 2):

Then you would do it the same way as you would without `MergeAdapter`:

- Wrap the `ListView` in a `vertical` `LinearLayout`
- Put your footer in the `LinearLayout`, after the `ListView`